# Split mesh at a specific point

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm wondering if it'd be possible to make a script for splitting meshes to simple shapes at a certain point. Split it to prevent vertex A and B to exist in the same object.

---

[image]

Comment: Coul you spend a few more words about what exactly are you trying to achieve? What would the final mesh be in your example?

Comment: The upper part would be one object, the lower second. I need to automate splitting the meshes this way so an application I use (which reads only vertex points) knows what to do. If I put the vertex points as-is, the application would see a cube because it would connect all the vertices to each other.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. A few more questions: how to recognize where each mesh should be splitted? what if the mesh is a sphere, a torus...? which tasks are you exactly trying to automate?

Comment: It'll be used as a collision mesh. The structure of the collision mesh is structured as shapes. Each shape has few vertices that are interconnected. I need to appropriately split a complex shape to match the collision accurately. Spheres shouldn't be a problem, though toruses could be troublesome. Thankfully it'll be mostly really simple shapes, like a room.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nevermind, I did some research and found out 'convex decomposition' is what I want. I ended up using [V-HACD Blender addon](https://github.com/andyp123/blender_vhacd).